# Power BI | How to split text values in a table by a keyword

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to split a string value of a column by a keyword, using DAX. As in, I want to retrieve texts from a sentence that contains a specific(fixed) keyword. For example, if my keyword is "error", then the following should happen.

[image]

Is there a way I can do that? My intuition is 1)split the text by '.', 2)find a sentence that contains the keyword, here "error", 3)get sentences from(inclusive) the sentence that contains the keyword "error".

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR T = Table1[Text]
VAR MyKeyword = "error"
RETURN
    MID(
        T,
        IFERROR(
            FIND(
                "Ω",
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    LEFT( T, FIND( MyKeyword, T ) ),
                    ".",
                    "Ω",
                    LEN( LEFT( T, FIND( MyKeyword, T ) ) )
                        - LEN( SUBSTITUTE( LEFT( T, FIND( MyKeyword, T ) ), ".", "" ) )
                )
            ) + 1,
            1
        ),
        999
    )
```

Note that `FIND` is case-sensitive. Amend to `SEARCH` for a case-insensitive version.